# I am using following PHP code for trigger creation but always get error, please help me to resolve it

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using following PHP code for trigger creation but always get error, please help me to resolve it.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','rainserver');
    mysql_select_db('information_schema');
                echo $trgquery = "DELIMITER $$ DROP TRIGGER `update_data` $$ CREATE TRIGGER `update_data` AFTER UPDATE on `jos_menu` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.menutype != OLD.menutype) THEN
INSERT INTO jos_menuaudit set menuid=OLD.id, oldvalue = OLD.menutype, newvalue = NEW.menutype, field = 'menutype';
END IF;
IF (NEW.name != OLD.name) THEN
INSERT INTO jos_menuaudit set menuid=OLD.id, oldvalue = OLD.name,

newvalue = NEW.name, field = 'name';
END IF;
IF (NEW.alias != OLD.alias) THEN
INSERT INTO jos_menuaudit set menuid=OLD.id, oldvalue = OLD.alias,

newvalue = NEW.alias, field = 'alias';
END IF;
END$$ DELIMITER ;";
                echo "<br>";
        //$trig = mysqli_query($link,$trgquery) or die("Error Exist".mysqli_error($link));
         $trig = mysql_query($trgquery) or die("Error Exist".mysql_error());
```

I get the error as:

```
Error ExistYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ DROP TRIGGER `update_data` $$ CREATE TRIGGER `update_data` AFTER UPDATE on `j' at line 1
```

PLease help me to create my trigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what's wrong. `DELIMITER $$ DROP ...` isn't a valid statement. Part of the reason for this is `delimiter` is a MySQL command, not a statement. Another reason is the "$$" in "DELIMITER $$" is part of the command and thus doesn't terminate the command. You still need to include the old delimiter.

According to the documentation, [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) doesn't support multiple statements, so you'll have to issue separate queries for each one. Better yet, switch to the newer mysqli driver, whose [`multi_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function works for multiple statements in a single query. mysqli also supports prepared statements, which doesn't matter so much in your example, but does in most other situations. [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) is even newer and also supports [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), and I believe the PDO MySQL driver supports multi-queries.

As an alternative to triggers, row-based [binary logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html) will record changes made to tables in a database.

Comment: Thanks Outis.. Ur Guide resolved my problem, I executed the queries separately... Thanks Again